# Адрес почтового ящика в админке битрикса

Tags: windows, битрикс, email, настройки

При установке битрикса указал почтовый ящика владельца. Где в админке битрикса можно найти адрес почтового ящика?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Настройки - Пользователи - Список пользователей
2. Настройки - Настройки продукта - Настройки модулей - Главный модуль
3. Настройки - Настройки продукта - Сайты - Список сайтов